# Import an Android project from svn,Err:Cannot find System Java Compiler

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I Import an Android project from svn.
Run it and AS show me this

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'`

> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.`

[image]

But I can run other android projects I wrote. There can't be wrong with System Java Compiler. How to make this right?

Ps: i'm a beginner in English. Forgive me if there's wrong in my words.